# Asus ROG Strix 17 G733 shutdown pops on any keyboard action

Tags: drivers, nvidia, asus

recentlty I bought Asus ROG Strix 17 G733 laptop and tried install ubuntu 20.04 and ubuntu 20.10.
Main problem I found on it is that on each touch of keyboard, ubuntu pops the shutdown window (will shutdown in 60 seconds ...)

tried install - reinstall nvidia drivers, it shuts down on boot.

NVIDIA® GeForce RTX™ 3080

AMD Ryzen™ 9 5900HX Processor 3.3 GHz

32GB DDR4-3200 SO-DIMM x 2

Did anybody encoutered same issue ? related to shutdown on input and other fixes

HELP

Comment: Update, with USB keyboard - works ok

Comment: I am having same issues with ubuntu 21 , I updated the kernel to 5.11.18-051118-generic , install nvidia drivers for 3060. Did anyone find solution ?